# How to send CheckBoxList items to a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send 2 colors like blue and red from CheckBoxList to a method which takes 4 optional parameters and print final combined result.

this is the checkboxlist:

```
 Choose Two Colors:
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>Red</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Blue</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Yellow</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Green</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This is a method which takes 4 optional parameters:

```
    static string ColorMixer(string Blue = "NotDefined", string Yellow = "NotDefined", string Red = "NotDefined",
    string Green = "NotDefined")
{

    string blue = Blue;
    string yellow = Yellow;
    string red = Red;
    string green = Green;
    string results;
    if (blue.Equals("Blue")&&yellow.Equals("Yellow"))
    {
        results = "GREEN";
        return results;
    }
    if (red.Equals("Red")& green.Equals("Green"))
    {
        results = "Brown";
        return results;
    }

   the rest of codes goes here ....

    else
    {
        results = "Result is Unspecified";
    }
    return results;
}
```

Now when someone chooses two colors from Checkboxlist I want to get two color with codes like this:

```
 protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {

            string selectedoptions;
            selectedoptions = item.Text;
        }

    }

}
```

And then send the selected string items as named parameters to the method

How we can get selected colors from string "selectedoptions" and then format it like?

```
  ColorMix(Blue:"Blue",Red:"Red")
```

Where the "Blue" and "Red" are selected colors by the user.

Comment: Kindly identify your problem or the error you got !

Comment: simply I want when someone chooses two colors from checkboxlist ,  I would be able to send items as named parameter to a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not ASP.Net but I am pretty sure the same would apply. I do not think you are using the right event for what you are trying to do. The event `CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged` fires, every time the user clicks into the `CheckBoxList` and changes which item is selected. The event fires even if a check box was not changed. Granted, you could do what needs to be done here, like check which check boxes are checked and pass some variables to a method, however You will do this EVERY time the user changes the selection.

I am guessing a button would be a better control to fire your color method. This way you are not looping thru the items until this button is pressed. Then, you can loop through the list and grab the checked colors. It is not clear what you want to do if there is only one (1) color checked or three or more, since the post indicates you wanted to pass only two colors.

Below (c# code) is the code I used with a `CheckedListBox` where items are named Red, Blue, Green and Yellow. I used a `Button_Click` event instead of the `CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event. When the button is pressed it simply loops through the list and displays the item index, name and its checked state.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Make a list of the checked colors you want to pass
  //List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
  int index;
  foreach (string item in checkedListBox1.Items) {
    index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item);
    string checkState = checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(index).ToString(); 
    MessageBox.Show("Item on line " + index + " name: " + item +
                    " is currently: " + checkState);
  }
}
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thank you so much, it's very nice approach